# vmware-tools and open-vm-tools-desktop aren't offering monitor resolutions anymore

Tags: vmware, display-resolution

There are tons of similar questions about this, but they always end up with "install the tools".

I have Debian running in VMware Workstation Player 12 on a 1440p monitor. VM settings are set to "use host settings" and memory upped to 764mb.

At first I installed vmware-tools (official one) and it was working great. Auto-resize, full resolution and I could reboot it fine.

One year later, I booted the VM on a gparted live CD in order to resize the partition (which worked), but when I came back to the OS, resolution was stuck to 800x600.

I tried:

`vmware-uninstall-tools.pl`
`reboot`
 reinstall with `vmware-uninstall-tools.pl`,
 `reboot`, no dice.

I then learned about the open version that is supposedly better. So again I tried:

`vmware-uninstall-tools.pl`
`reboot`
`apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop`
`reboot`, no dice.

The copy/paste functionality works, but the resolution is stuck. No matter how many time I reinstall the tools it just won't resize to my native resolution.

`xrandr -q` lists the same set of 6 resolution than the "Displays" dialog have, which are all tiny. I tried to add mine manually following a guide but only got a black screen.

How can I get back to 1440p as before?

Answer (score 1):

This question had the answer:

[Gparted LiveCD ISO breaks Ubuntu 14.04.4 desktop resolution in Vmware Fusion 7.1.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747555/gparted-livecd-iso-breaks-ubuntu-14-04-4-desktop-resolution-in-vmware-fusion-7-1)

Open the config file is called .vmx. Removed the line 'svga.guestBackedPrimaryAware = "TRUE"'.